# After updae to Lunar 23.04 GQRX gone, Pulseaudio DUMMY audio Gone, DSD-FME fails

Tags: pulseaudio, pipewire

I used Ubuntu to decode digital audio streaming from an SDR device via GQRX as nearly my only hobby.  After upgrading to Lunar, this is completely removed.  Main gr-osmo components of GQRX were removed, as was pulse audio replaced by Pipewire.  I can no longer run GQRX after trying to re-install with apt install gqrx-sdr.  I tried to reinstall Pulseaudio.  I CAN download and run Gqrx-2.16-x86_64.AppImage, and audio does work.  I cannot however 'see' the dummy audio output for using DSD-FME for digital decoding which is the best and main idea behind part of doing this.  When I try to add back the loopback, I get: No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.  Using soapy with an SDRplay has also been completely destroyed but i have Win11 for that.

I have made some headway with the following steps:

$pulseaudio --daemonize

i was then able to

$pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=virtual_sink  sink_properties=device.description=Virtual_Sink

however this does not persist through a reboot so i had to make an alias to reload the sink every reboot.

Has anyone also upgraded who also uses GQRX+DSD-FME and worked this out?
Thank you